# Highcharts: how to know a Y value is plotted?

Tags: highcharts

I have a column chart and it allows panning.

```
chart: {
        type: 'column',
        zoomType: 'x',
        panning: true,
        panKey: 'shift',
        resetZoomButton: {
            theme: {
                display: 'none'
            }
       }
}
```

I notice a situation that the column's value in the X axis is plotted, but its Y value is not. See the following two images:

1. Before panning

[image]

2. After panning to the left side a little, the 9/12/14 column disappears but its date is still there.

[image]

How can I know which column is actually plotted? The reason I am asking about this is that I need to calculate the Y total for those columns that do show up. Highcharts has API allowing you to know exactly which values are displayed on the X axis, from which you can get corresponding Y values for a total. However, for the total, I don't want to include a plotted X value whose Y value is not plotted.

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**

Here is the jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mddc/oz1v951o/5/
You need to zoom in and then do panning.

Comment: Can you do a jsFiddle reproduction of this issue?

Comment: Jugal, I created a jsfiddle demo. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a bug, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3454). Thanks! Workaround would be to add some empty point (null point) for value before first category, but that may break visual side od the graph, though.

Comment: Pawel, nice to hear from you on this. Sounds like I am pushing a bit hard on Highcharts? :-)

Comment: I checked, it works under 50 points but above 50 it does what you said : http://jsfiddle.net/oz1v951o/7/